# Xcode 5 - UIImageView won't show up on any iOS before iOS 7

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I made an update to my app and after one of my friends updated my app on his phone, the images wouldn't show up. This happened to another person who didn't have iOS 7 but anyone who does, the app works fine.

Can I make it so that only people with iOS 7 or later can have it?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you fix the issue? If you need help then provide more details about the image view giving you issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Issue, I believe it's a bug and as a workaround change the auto-resize masks worked for me.

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19518892/1107651)